# Create blue event button on right corner in SAP B1 matrix

Tags: c#, sapb1

I want to Create a blue event button on the right corner of the SAP Business One matrix to adjust the size of the matrix

[image]

Comment: SAP can be programmed in C# now? Cool. Maybe I can get back into that business

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.